# Codename One Camera Kit video resolution and max time

Tags: codenameone

To don't get too much heavy video files or "strange" file formats (because I need to send video post to a server for a social app), I would like to set:

- a max video acquiring resolution (I suppose that acquiring at the max resolution of recent smartphones can produce too much heavy files to be sent to a server or to be shared with other apps);
- a max recording time;
- the use of the "mp4" standard format (that I suppose to be the most compatible one, however I'm not sure that this is the best choice).

All of them are possible using the [Camera KIT CN1Lib](https://github.com/codenameone/CameraKitCodenameOne)? I didn't see too much documentation... The target is Android and iOS.

If it's not possible, any alternative solution?

*Note for the readers: this question is specific for Codename One only.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video file should be mp4, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

You can set the quality using `setVideoQuality`. It accepts one of the following constants from the `Constants` interface:  `VIDEO_QUALITY_480P`, `VIDEO_QUALITY_720P`, `VIDEO_QUALITY_1080P`, `VIDEO_QUALITY_2160P`, `VIDEO_QUALITY_HIGHEST`, `VIDEO_QUALITY_LOWEST`, `VIDEO_QUALITY_QVGA`.

I'm guessing that `VIDEO_QUALITY_HIGHEST` should work.

`captureVideo` and `stopVideo` start and stop capture respectively. You can limit the max time based on your code and just invoke `stopVideo()` based on arbitrary logic.